# How to convert HCT to RGB

Tags: typescript, colors

I was wondering what the algorithm is to convert [Google's new color space](https://material.io/blog/science-of-color-design), HCT to RGB. For example, when you start with the three HCT values (hue, chroma, and tone) like: `hct(156, 122, 50)` how would you then convert that to `rgb(0, 137, 75)`?

Google has open sourced their [Material Color Utilities](https://github.com/material-foundation/material-color-utilities/tree/main), and there is a typescript library, which in theory sounds useful... But I could not find any straightforward way to use their utilities to do what I need, or even the algorithm buried in the code somewhere.

Comment: You can convert the HCT to HSL, and then convert HSL to RGB!

Comment: @ArAsH is that something that can be done with the Material Color Utilities? As far as I've been able to figure out so far, I can only convert a given RGB color to HCT like so: `Hct.fromInt(rgbColor)`. I couldn't figure out any way to convert HCT to HSL (or any other color space).

Comment: No, I am not sure that it can be done with the Material Color Utilities.

Comment: Note: considering the tiny amount of documentation online, and the "vaporware" type of writing in the introductory document, you may consider it as Google method: "do preliminary work, get a promotion and forget about the project". "There is no online tool, so let's create a colour space". "Let's proof it with compression of a well know painting which cause well known sensation (moving sun)" (so: do not do it, but for very artistic purposes: it is not good design). And read documentation is lacking. (and implicit: "projections are too much math")

Comment: I do think the thrust of the HCT color space makes sense. I like the idea of normalizing lightness (tone) across all hues to adjust for human perception. It feels more accurate and makes the idea of contrast ratios between colors easier to understand at an instinctive level. I do wish there was more published about the math than just the one introductory blog post.

Answer (score 0):

Using the [Material Color Utilities](https://github.com/material-foundation/material-color-utilities/tree/main), you can convert HCT to an RGB hex code.

```
import { Hct } from "@material/material-color-utilities";

const color = { hue: 156, chroma: 122, tone: 50 };
const hctObj = Hct.from(color.hue, color.chroma, color.tone);
const rgbHex = hctObj.argb.toString(16).slice(2);

console.log('Your hex is #' + rgbHex); // Your hex is #00894b
```

Starting with hue, chroma, and tone values, create an `Hct` color object using the `.from()` method. That color object contains an `argb` property which is an integer. You can use the `.toString(16)` method to convert the integer to hexidecimal, and then `.slice(2)` to remove the alpha data from the hex code.

That all said, it would be very interesting to see the actual algorithm spelled out in a more straightforward manner.

Answer (score 0):

**Property argb has been marked as private.**

```js
export declare class Hct {
    // ...
    private argb;
    // ...
}
```

**Dangerous Behavior**，We can continue to use it. It is recommended to use the form of [] to avoid typescript error prompts.

```js
const sourceColor: [number, number, number] = [200, 50, 50]

// HCT to ARGB（type of the hctArgb is string）
const hctArgb = Hct.from(...sourceColor)['argb']

// ARGB string to RGBA object
/* the output like： 
 * {
 *   "r": 0,
 *   "g": 132,
 *   "b": 136,
 *   "a": 255
 * }
 */
const rgba = rgbaFromArgb(hctArgb)
console.log(rgba)

/* the output like：
 * rgb(0, 132, 136)
 */
const { r, g, b} = rgba
const rgb = `rgb(${r}, ${g}, ${b})`
console.log(rgb);
```